# How to upgrade React app to latest Android API level

Tags: android, react-native

So, I've been tasked with taking over a React-Native app that hasn't been touched for 3+ years. It seems a lot has changed since then and I was wondering how to start.

My main requirement is to get it to work with Android API Level 33 as Android will no longer show apps lower than that in the Play Store fairly soon.

The app is using:

```
Gradle v3.6.0
Android API Level 29
React v16.13.1
React Native v0.62.2
```

Is it usually better to try and incrementally upgrade apps bit by bit? Or start off with a new template React Native project that use all the latest versions and try and gradually import the code and settings into it.

The app is pretty complicated with a lot of dependencies and custom configurations.